# CSS3 hover button rolling background color change

Tags: css

Is there an easy way and less code to change the background color with rolling effect? Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/Das8r/

```
<a href="#"><span data-title="Text Link">Text Link</span></a>

    a{
        color: #03c;
        display: inline-block;
        overflow: hidden;
        vertical-align: top;

    }

    a span{
        display: block;
        position: relative;
        padding: 0 2px;
        -webkit-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -moz-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -o-transition: all 400ms ease;
        -ms-transition: all 400ms ease;
        transition: all 400ms ease;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -moz-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -o-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        -ms-transform-style: preserve-3d;
        transform-style: preserve-3d;
    }

    a:hover span {
        background: #03c;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
        -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
        -o-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
        -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
        transform: translate3d( 0px, 0px, -30px ) rotateX( 90deg );
    }

    a span:after {
        content: attr(data-title);
        display: block;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        top: 0;
        padding: 0 2px;
        color: #fff;
        background: #03c;
        -webkit-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -moz-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -o-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -ms-transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        transform-origin: 50% 0%;
        -webkit-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
        -moz-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
        -o-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
        -ms-transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
        transform: translate3d( 0px, 105%, 0px ) rotateX( -90deg );
    }
```

Comment: nope looks pretty dry to me. You could use a precompilier like compass  to make it more manageable.

Answer (score 0):

You can make Minify your by Compressing to minified version or you should use CSS Pre-Processor like [SASS](http://sass-lang.com) (I Recommend).

CSS on its own can be fun, but stylesheets are getting larger, more complex, and harder to maintain. 
This is where a preprocessor can help. [Sass](http://sass-lang.com) lets you use features that don't exist in CSS yet like 
variables, nesting, mixins, inheritance and other nifty goodies that make writing CSS fun again.